# Which pyzmq implementation has the fastest throughput between @gen.coroutine, @asyncio.coroutine and async?

Tags: performance, python-3.x, tornado, zeromq, pyzmq

Currently in pzmq there are multiple ways to implement an asynchronous IO Loop all mentioned in the documentation.
http://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/index.html

From a pure performance point of view, it is not clear in the documentation if the choices are equivalent. These are:

- Tornado @gen.coroutine
- Native @asyncio.coroutine
- Tornado async

So, which one has the best throughput in messages per second in a typical PUSH-PULL scenario as shown in the documentation examples? Why do we see a difference between them?

Comment: I was pretty interested in the **Why** part of the answer, which seems to be missing. Do you plan, Dorian, to analyse the Why part either? zmq.Stopwatch{.start() | .stop() } class-methods  provide down to [us] resolution, if going the harder way, or Intel Python ( interesting per-se ) provides a python live-application profiling in "attach" mode of V-tune XE analyser, showing the worst performance blockers immediately in the non-decorated source code. Will you go in for details, for realistic reasons of the just observed performance-differences?

Comment: Would be an interesting exercise, but my main concern is to finish my implementation than premature optimization as mentioned before.

Comment: A "premature optimisation" is not the case. Your O/P has posted the question ***(cit.:)* "Why do we see a difference between them?"** which means it was your own question that you considered important to get answer for, wasn't it? Next, V-tune XT has zero overhead to "attach" the ready-made analyser to a live application, so you get answers ( directly in source code ) at zero additional efforts. Not all performance tuning procedures can say the same. (I do not advocate for any particular product, but mention a set of cheapest tools to get your, not mine, question answered as you have asked to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Results**

Contrary to my expectations, it seems both asyncio implementations in pyzmq are slower than the "legacy" tornado one.

Tornado @gen.coroutine:

```
Avg. Speed: 2160.26 msg/s
```

Native @asyncio.coroutine:

```
Avg. Speed: 1697.66 msg/s
```

Tornado async:

```
Avg. Speed: 1695.29 msg/s
```

Also, the two asyncio implementations show bursts of up to 3536.27 msg/s every now and then, whereas the Tornado @gen.coroutine is very stable in throughput.

### **Test Code**

For comparing I have used modified versions of:

Tornado @gen.coroutine:
https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/master/examples/eventloop/coroutines.py

Native @asyncio.coroutine:
https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/master/examples/asyncio/coroutines.py

Tornado async: (Python 3.5+ only; included additional print coroutine)
https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/master/examples/asyncio/tornado_asyncio.py

The modification consists of displaying the number of average messages per second every 5 seconds instead of the dots. In the PULL coroutine, I increment `n = n + 1` and then in the printing coroutine I calculate `v = n / (time.time() - start)` and display it. Also there, I reset `n = 0` and `start = time.time()` every 10,000 messages to prevent any offset effects in the measurement.

### **Environment**

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost 4.6.3-300.fc24.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 24 20:52:41 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.1

>>> zmq.__version__
'15.3.0'

>>> tornado.version
'4.3'
```

Comment: Thanks for doing this research! The results are surprising to me as well. I believe the reason for the difference is that there is some overhead for crossing the boundary between the different styles of coroutine, and pyzmq's internals are using Tornado coroutines (this is a higher impact than I expected; there may be room for improvement). As your application becomes more complex and you have more functions calling each other, the more efficient `async def` coroutines should become faster.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I will take your advice and go with the future-proof `async def` instead of falling into the premature optimization trap.